# How to modify a built-in model from Keras applications

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am training the pre-trained keras application models on some small dataset and then visualize what happens in each layer of the model to the images using Grad-CAM. Basically, I want to see which layers are in charge of recognizing the points of interest in the image.
What I want to do after that is to remove the layers that do not contribute to my goal and see if the resulting architecture delivers the same metrics or it will become less efficient.

I wasn't able to find how to remove certain layers from a built-in Keras application model. does any one know if this is possible and if yes, how?

### **Update**

Finally solved it. Here is the code:

```
initial_model = tf.keras.applications.VGG16(weights = 'imagenet',include_top = False)
initial_model.trainable = False

#adding all the layers from the architecture into a list
layers = [l for l in initial_model.layers]

#building a new model with the existing layers with their 'imagenet' weights
modified_model = keras.Sequential()
inputs = keras.Input(shape = (None,None,3))
modified_model.add(inputs)

#removing the last block from my VGG16 architecture and
for layer in layers:
  if 'block5' not in layer.name:
    layer._inbound_nodes = []
    layer._outbound_nodes = []
    modified_model.add(layer)


modified_model.add(keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D())
#my data has 38 classes, this last layer depends on the number of classes
modified_model.add(keras.layers.Dense(38, activation="softmax"))

modified_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])


history = modified_model.fit(ds_train,
                    epochs = 40,
                    validation_data = ds_valid,
                    verbose = 1)
```

Comment: If you straight up remove a layer from a pre-trained network, the reset of the network becomes invalid. At this point you have to re-train the network, so might as well create a new model.

Comment: That won't be what I'm looking for. The thing is, training the model from scratch with ~5000 images won't give me good results. I was counting on transfer learning for that. Well, I should think of another way.  Anyway, thanks Bhupen.

Comment: Ok, let be clear about one thing that may have come across incorrectly. You can remove outer layers from pretrained networks and then just train the newly added layers (this is how transfer learning works in general). What you cant do is remove layers in the middle, network becomes invalid after then point and needs to be retrained at least from then point on.

Comment: there was no misunderstanding. I know I can remove the outer layers. basically, I wanted to visualize what happens in the middle layers of the model with Grad-CAM and then remove the layers that do not particularly help me in my task, according to the Grad-CAM results. and then re-train the new model with simpler architecture and see if it yields the same accuracy/loss or not.

Comment: @Bhupen I may have found a solution for this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62952612/removing-a-layer-from-the-middle-of-a-keras-model

only the quesitons part is similar to what I was looking for.:)